# Algorithm for pow(float, float)

Tags: algorithm, math, floating-point

I need an efficent algorithm to do math::power function between two floats, 
do you have any idea how to do this, (i need the algorithm not to use the function itself)

Comment: Have you heard of Taylor/Maclaurin series?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: `pow(x,y) = exp(y*log(x))` - so if you are able to use `exp()` and `log()` you are done (or implement the series)

Comment: looking at that wikipedia article it look more like pow(x,y) = exp(x*log(y)) [Where x is the base and y is the exponent]

Comment: @pcantin exp(y*log(x)) = exp(log(x^y)) = x^y

Comment: @ring0 & @Nabb Sorry my bad. It must be the Baileys in my coffee

Comment: @pcantin try the Calva instead :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The general algorithm tends to be computing the float power as the combination of the integer power and the remaining root. The integer power is fairly straightforward, the root can be computed using either [Newton - Raphson method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html) or [Taylor series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html). IIRC [numerical recipes in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431085) has some text on this. There are other (potentially better) methods for doing this too, but this would make a reasonable starting point for what is a surprisingly complex problem to implement. Note also that some implementations use lookup tables and a number of tricks to reduce the computation required.

Answer (score 26):

Since IEEE-754 binary floating-point numbers are fractions, computing a<sup>b</sup> is technically an algebraic operation. However the common approach to implement `powf(float a, float b)` is as e<sup>b * log a</sup>, i.e. using transcendental functions.

There are a few caveats, however. `log a` is undefined for `a < 0`, while `powf()` allows computation with some negative `a`. Exponentiation, in the form of `expf()` suffers from error magnification, as I explained in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868834/precision-of-calculations-after-exponent-function). This requires us to compute `log a` with higher than single precision for an accurate `powf()` result. There are various techniques to achieve this, a simple way is to use limited amounts of double-`float` computation, references for which I provided in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769881/emulate-double-using-2-floats). The essence of double-`float` is that each floating-point operand is represented as a pair of `float` values called the "head" and the "tail", which satisfy the relation |tail| ≤ ½ * [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) (|head|) when properly normalized.

The [c](/questions/tagged/c) code below shows an exemplary implementation of this approach. It assumes that the IEEE 754-2008 operation FMA (fused multiply-add) is available, which is exposed in C as the standard math functions `fma()`, `fmaf()`. It does not provide for handling of `errno` or floating-point exceptions, but it does provide for the correct handling of all 18 special cases enumerated by the ISO C standard. Tests have been performed with denormal support enabled; the code may or may not work properly within a non-IEEE-754 flush-to-zero (FTZ) environment.

The exponentiation part employs a simple argument reduction based directly on the semi-logarithmic encoding of floating-point numbers, then applies a polynomial [minimax approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_approximation_algorithm) on the primary approximation interval. The logarithm computation is based on `log(x) = 2 atanh ((x-1) / (x+1))`, combined with selective use of double-`float` computation, to achieve a relative accuracy of 8.3e-10. The computation of `b * log a` is performed as a double-`float` operation, the accuracy of the final exponentiation is improved by linear interpolation, by observing that e<sup>x</sup> is its own derivative, and that therefore e<sup>x+y</sup> ≅ e<sup>x</sup> + y ⋅ e<sup>x</sup>, when |y| ≪ |x|.

Double-`float` computation becomes a bit iffy near overflow boundaries, there are two instances of this in the code. When the head portion of the input to `exp` is just causing the result to overflow to infinity, the tail portion may be negative, such that the result of `powf()` is actually finite. One way to address this is to decrease the value of the "head" by one [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) in such a case, an alternative is to compute the head via addition in round-to-zero mode where readily available, since this will ensure like signs for head and tail. The other caveat is that if the exponentiation does overflow, we cannot interpolate the result, as doing so would create a NaN.

It should be noted that the accuracy of the logarithm computation used here is not sufficient to ensure a faithfully-rounded `powf()` implementation, but it provides a reasonably small error (the maximum error I have found in extensive testing is less than 2 ulps) and it allows the code to be kept reasonably simple for the purpose of demonstrating relevant design principles.

```c
#include <stdint.h> // for uint32_t
#include <string.h> // for memcpy
#include <math.h>   // for frexpf, ldexpf, isinf, nextafterf

#define PORTABLE (1) // 0=bit-manipulation of 'float', 1= math library functions

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a) 
{ 
    uint32_t r; 
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r); 
    return r; 
}

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a) 
{ 
    float r; 
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r); 
    return r; 
}

/* Compute log(a) with extended precision, returned as a double-float value 
   loghi:loglo. Maximum relative error: 8.5626e-10.
*/
void my_logf_ext (float a, float *loghi, float *loglo)
{
    const float LOG2_HI =  6.93147182e-1f; //  0x1.62e430p-1
    const float LOG2_LO = -1.90465421e-9f; // -0x1.05c610p-29
    const float SQRT_HALF = 0.70710678f;
    float m, r, i, s, t, p, qhi, qlo;
    int e;

    /* Reduce argument to m in [sqrt(0.5), sqrt(2.0)] */
#if PORTABLE
    m = frexpf (a, &e);
    if (m < SQRT_HALF) {
        m = m + m;
        e = e - 1;
    }
    i = (float)e;
#else // PORTABLE
    const float POW_TWO_M23 = 1.19209290e-7f; // 0x1.0p-23
    const float POW_TWO_P23 = 8388608.0f; // 0x1.0p+23
    const float FP32_MIN_NORM = 1.175494351e-38f; // 0x1.0p-126
    i = 0.0f;
    /* fix up denormal inputs */
    if (a < FP32_MIN_NORM){
        a = a * POW_TWO_P23;
        i = -23.0f;
    }
    e = (float_as_uint32 (a) - float_as_uint32 (SQRT_HALF)) & 0xff800000;
    m = uint32_as_float (float_as_uint32 (a) - e);
    i = fmaf ((float)e, POW_TWO_M23, i);
#endif // PORTABLE
    /* Compute q = (m-1)/(m+1) as a double-float qhi:qlo */
    p = m + 1.0f;
    m = m - 1.0f;
    r = 1.0f / p;
    qhi = r * m;
    qlo = r * fmaf (qhi, -m, fmaf (qhi, -2.0f, m));
    /* Approximate atanh(q), q in [sqrt(0.5)-1, sqrt(2)-1] */ 
    s = qhi * qhi;
    r =             0.1293334961f;  // 0x1.08c000p-3
    r = fmaf (r, s, 0.1419928074f); // 0x1.22cd9cp-3
    r = fmaf (r, s, 0.2000148296f); // 0x1.99a162p-3
    r = fmaf (r, s, 0.3333332539f); // 0x1.555550p-2
    t = fmaf (qhi, qlo + qlo, fmaf (qhi, qhi, -s)); // s:t = (qhi:qlo)**2
    p = s * qhi;
    t = fmaf (s, qlo, fmaf (t, qhi, fmaf (s, qhi, -p))); // p:t = (qhi:qlo)**3
    s = fmaf (r, p, fmaf (r, t, qlo));
    r = 2 * qhi;
    /* log(a) = 2 * atanh(q) + i * log(2) */
    t = fmaf ( LOG2_HI, i, r);
    p = fmaf (-LOG2_HI, i, t);
    s = fmaf ( LOG2_LO, i, fmaf (2.f, s, r - p));
    *loghi = p = t + s;    // normalize double-float result
    *loglo = (t - p) + s;
}

/* Compute exponential base e. No checking for underflow and overflow. Maximum
   ulp error = 0.86565 
*/
float my_expf_unchecked (float a)
{
    float f, j, r;
    int i;

    // exp(a) = 2**i * exp(f); i = rintf (a / log(2))
    j = fmaf (1.442695f, a, 12582912.f) - 12582912.f; // 0x1.715476p0, 0x1.8p23
    f = fmaf (j, -6.93145752e-1f, a); // -0x1.62e400p-1  // log_2_hi 
    f = fmaf (j, -1.42860677e-6f, f); // -0x1.7f7d1cp-20 // log_2_lo 
    i = (int)j;
    // approximate r = exp(f) on interval [-log(2)/2, +log(2)/2]
    r =             1.37805939e-3f;  // 0x1.694000p-10
    r = fmaf (r, f, 8.37312452e-3f); // 0x1.125edcp-7
    r = fmaf (r, f, 4.16695364e-2f); // 0x1.555b5ap-5
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.66664720e-1f); // 0x1.555450p-3
    r = fmaf (r, f, 4.99999851e-1f); // 0x1.fffff6p-2
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.00000000e+0f); // 0x1.000000p+0
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.00000000e+0f); // 0x1.000000p+0
    // exp(a) = 2**i * r
#if PORTABLE
    r = ldexpf (r, i);
#else // PORTABLE
    float s, t;
    uint32_t ia = (i > 0) ? 0u : 0x83000000u;
    s = uint32_as_float (0x7f000000u + ia);
    t = uint32_as_float (((uint32_t)i << 23) - ia);
    r = r * s;
    r = r * t;
#endif // PORTABLE
    return r;
}

/* a**b = exp (b * log (a)), where a > 0, and log(a) is computed with extended 
   precision as a double-float. Maxiumum error found across 2**42 test cases:
   1.97302 ulp @ (0.71162397, -256.672424).
*/
float my_powf_core (float a, float b)
{
    const float MAX_IEEE754_FLT = uint32_as_float (0x7f7fffff);
    const float EXP_OVFL_BOUND = 88.7228394f; // 0x1.62e430p+6f;
    const float EXP_OVFL_UNFL_F = 104.0f;
    const float MY_INF_F = uint32_as_float (0x7f800000);
    float lhi, llo, thi, tlo, phi, plo, r;

    /* compute lhi:llo = log(a) */
    my_logf_ext (a, &lhi, &llo);
    /* compute phi:plo = b * log(a) */
    thi = lhi * b;
    if (fabsf (thi) > EXP_OVFL_UNFL_F) { // definitely overflow / underflow
        r = (thi < 0.0f) ? 0.0f : MY_INF_F;
    } else {
        tlo = fmaf (lhi, b, -thi);
        tlo = fmaf (llo, b, +tlo);
        /* normalize intermediate result thi:tlo, giving final result phi:plo */
#if FAST_FADD_RZ
        phi = __fadd_rz (thi, tlo);// avoid premature ovfl in exp() computation
#else // FAST_FADD_RZ
        phi = thi + tlo;
        if (phi == EXP_OVFL_BOUND){// avoid premature ovfl in exp() computation
#if PORTABLE
            phi = nextafterf (phi, 0.0f);
#else // PORTABLE
            phi = uint32_as_float (float_as_uint32 (phi) - 1);
#endif // PORTABLE
        }
#endif // FAST_FADD_RZ
        plo = (thi - phi) + tlo;
        /* exp'(x) = exp(x); exp(x+y) = exp(x) + exp(x) * y, for |y| << |x| */
        r = my_expf_unchecked (phi);
        /* prevent generation of NaN during interpolation due to r = INF */
        if (fabsf (r) <= MAX_IEEE754_FLT) {
            r = fmaf (plo, r, r);
        }
    }
    return r;
}

float my_powf (float a, float b)
{
    const float MY_INF_F = uint32_as_float (0x7f800000);
    const float MY_NAN_F = uint32_as_float (0xffc00000);
    int expo_odd_int;
    float r;

    /* special case handling per ISO C specification */
    expo_odd_int = fmaf (-2.0f, floorf (0.5f * b), b) == 1.0f;
    if ((a == 1.0f) || (b == 0.0f)) {
        r = 1.0f;
    } else if (isnan (a) || isnan (b)) {
        r = a + b;  // convert SNaN to QNanN or trigger exception
    } else if (isinf (b)) {
        r = ((fabsf (a) < 1.0f) != (b < 0.0f)) ? 0.0f :  MY_INF_F;
        if (a == -1.0f) r = 1.0f;
    } else if (isinf (a)) {
        r = (b < 0.0f) ? 0.0f : MY_INF_F;
        if ((a < 0.0f) && expo_odd_int) r = -r;
    } else if (a == 0.0f) {
        r = (expo_odd_int) ? (a + a) : 0.0f;
        if (b < 0.0f) r = copysignf (MY_INF_F, r);
    } else if ((a < 0.0f) && (b != floorf (b))) {
        r = MY_NAN_F;
    } else {
        r = my_powf_core (fabsf (a), b);
        if ((a < 0.0f) && expo_odd_int) {
            r = -r;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to translate this code to a language that doesn't natively support fmaf, and am baffled by the algorithm.  According to [an online C compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/M_kdiccZC), `fmaf (1.442695f, a, 12582912.f) - 12582912.f`, when `a` is `1`, is just `1`?!  When I replace `fmaf(x, y, z)` with `(x*y)+z`, I instead get `1.442695f`.  What's up with this, and is there a way to implement this without `fmaf`?

Comment: Ah, I guess I need to change 0x1.8p23 to 0x1.8p53 if I'm using `double`?

Can you explain why `0x1.8`?

Comment: Also, where does `0x1.715476p0` come from?

Comment: @JasonGross Look at the comment above. 1/log(2) = `0x1.715476p0` = `1.442695f`

Comment: @JasonGross Sorry, overlooked the earlier question. The "magic" constants for conversion by addition are 2\*\*23+2\*\*22 for `float` and 2\*\*52+2\*\*51 for `double`, both when converting *signed* integers. The less significant bit in each case is there to absorb sign propagation. For *unsigned* conversion it is not needed. As for `FMA x,y,z`, in most cases one *cannot* simply replace it by `x*y+z`, as FMA uses the *full unrounded* product in the addition, and there is just one single rounding at the end. FMA was invented by IBM for this reason.