# Accurate computation of CDF of standard normal distribution using C standard math library

Tags: c, algorithm, math, floating-point

The standard C math library does not provide a function to compute the CDF of the standard normal distribution, `normcdf()`. It does, however, offer closely related functions: the error function, `erf()` and the complementary error function, `erfc()`. The fastest way to compute the CDF is often via the error function, using the predefined constant M_SQRT1_2 to represent √½:

```
double normcdf (double a) 
{
    return 0.5 + 0.5 * erf (M_SQRT1_2 * a);
}
```

Clearly, this suffers from massive subtractive cancellation in the negative half-plane and is not  suitable for the majority of applications. Since the cancellation issue is easily avoided by use of `erfc()`, which however is typically of somewhat lower performance than `erf()`, the most frequently recommended computation is:

```
double normcdf (double a) 
{
    return 0.5 * erfc (-M_SQRT1_2 * a);
}
```

Some testing shows that the maximum ulp error incurred in the negative half-plane is still rather large however. Using a double-precision implementation of `erfc()` accurate to 0.51 ulps, one can observe errors of 
up to 1705.44 ulps in `normcdf()`. The issue here is that the computational error in the input to `erfc()` is magnified by the exponential scaling that is inherent to `erfc()` (See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868834/precision-of-calculations-after-exponent-function) 
for an explanation of error magnification caused by exponentiation).

The following paper shows how one can achieve (nearly) correctly rounded, products when multiplying floating-point operands with arbitrary-precision constants such as √½:

Nicolas Brisebarre and Jean-Michel Muller, "Correctly rounded multiplication by arbitrary precision constants", *IEEE Transactions on Computers*, Vol. 57, No. 2, February 2008, pp. 165-174

The method advocated by the paper relies on the fused multiply-add operation, which is available on recent implementations of all common processor architectures, and is exposed in C via the standard math function `fma()`. This leads to the following version:

```
double normcdf (double a) 
{
    double SQRT_HALF_HI =  0x1.6a09e667f3bcd0p-01; //  7.0710678118654757e-01
    double SQRT_HALF_LO = -0x1.bdd3413b264560p-55; // -4.8336466567264567e-17

    return 0.5 * erfc (fma (-SQRT_HALF_HI, a, -SQRT_HALF_LO * a));
}
```

Tests show that this cuts the maximum error roughly in half compared to the previous version. Using the same highly-accurate `erfc()` implementation as before, the maximum observed error is 842.71 ulps. This is still far away from the usual goal of providing basic mathematical functions with an error of at most a few ulps.

Is there an efficient method that allows for the accurate computation of `normcdf()`, and that uses only functions available in the standard C math library?

Comment: Are you on a system where `long double` provides more precision than `double`?  If so, does using `erfl()` and `erfcl()` provide any assistance?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My currently used platforms either do not support `long double` or map `long double` to `double`. Otherwise, with `long double` mapped to 80-bit extended precision, double-double, or quadruple precision, my expectation would be that the simple formula based on `erfcl` would deliver results accurate to double precision, but I don't have a way of demonstrating that right now. On the other hand, even assuming computation via `erfl()` maps to full IEEE-754 quadruple precision, massive cancellation will lead to inaccurate results in the negative half-plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way around the accuracy limitations of the approaches outlined in the question is the limited use of double-double computation. This involves the computation of `-sqrt (0.5) * a` as a pair of `double` variables `h` and `l` in head/tail fashion. The high-order portion `h` of the product is passed to `erfc()`, while the low-order portion `l` is then used to interpolate the `erfc()` result, based on the local slope of the complementary error function at `h`.

The derivative of erfc(x) is -2 * exp (-x * x) / √π. However, one would like to avoid the fairly expensive computation of exp(-x * x). It is [known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html) that for x > 0, erfc(x) ~= 2 * exp (-x * x) / (√π * (x + sqrt (x* x + 4/π)). Therefore, asymptotically, 
erfc'(x) ~= -2 * x * erfc(x), and it follows that for |l| ≪|h|, erfc (h+l) ~= erfc (h) - 2 * h * l * erfc(h). The negation of the latter term can easily be pulled into the computation of `l`. One arrives at the following implementation for double precision (using IEEE-754 `binary64`):

```
double my_normcdf (double a)
{
    double h, l, r;
    const double SQRT_HALF_HI =  0x1.6a09e667f3bcd0p-01; //  7.0710678118654757e-01
    const double SQRT_HALF_LO = -0x1.bdd3413b264560p-55; // -4.8336466567264567e-17

    /* clamp input as normcdf(x) is either 0 or 1 asymptotically */
    if (fabs (a) > 38.625) a = (a < 0.0) ? -38.625 : 38.625;

    h = fma (-SQRT_HALF_HI, a, -SQRT_HALF_LO * a);
    l = fma (SQRT_HALF_LO, a, fma (SQRT_HALF_HI, a, h));
    r = erfc (h);
    if (h > 0.0) r = fma (2.0 * h * l, r, r);
    return 0.5 * r;
}
```

The maximum observed error, using the same `erfc()` implementation as used before, is 1.96 ulps. The corresponding single-precision implementation (using IEEE-754 `binary32`) is:

```
float my_normcdff (float a)
{
    float h, l, r;
    const float SQRT_HALF_HI = 0x1.6a09e6p-01f; // 7.07106769e-1
    const float SQRT_HALF_LO = 0x1.9fcef4p-27f; // 1.21016175e-8

    /* clamp input as normcdf(x) is either 0 or 1 asymptotically */
    if (fabsf (a) > 14.171875f) a = (a < 0.0f) ? -14.171875f : 14.171875f;

    h = fmaf (-SQRT_HALF_HI, a, -SQRT_HALF_LO * a);
    l = fmaf (SQRT_HALF_LO, a, fmaf (SQRT_HALF_HI, a, h));
    r = erfcf (h);
    if (h > 0.0f) r = fmaf (2.0f * h * l, r, r);
    return 0.5f * r;
}
```